# Regular expression for html/xhtml filename

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to work up a regular expression for the following:

"any number of characters, any character up to 'ch01' or 'chapter01' the next character cant be a number then any number of characters, any character up to a period and following the period there must be a html or xhtml"

Sorry if thats confusing but some test cases might be better help:

```
x = 'fdsafafsdch01fdsfdsf.xhtml' #pass
y = '9781599048970_ch01__s1_002.html' #pass
z = 'ch01.html' #pass
a = 'chapter019.xhtml' #fail
l = 'chapter01.html' #pass
m = 'chapter010-fn.xhtml' #fail
matches = [x, y, z, a, l, m]

for item in matches:
  print(bool(re.search('ch(apter)?01\D?.*\.x?html',  item)))
```

(#fail == `False`, #pass == `True`)

Currently all cases are returning `True`

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with `\D?`. This means "zero or one nondigits", so the regex parses `chapter019` as "chapter01" followed by zero nondigits, followed by one character, which it happily matches. Try having the `?` affect both the `\D` and the `.*` following it.

```
for item in matches:
  print(bool(re.search('ch(apter)?01(\D.*)?\.x?html',  item)))
```

Result:

```
True
True
True
False
True
False
```